# Is there a way to exempt files / folders from Coveralls test coverage scoring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, activeadmin, rspec-rails

My team is using coveralls.io in our CI process to give us an rspec coverage score. We're also using the ActiveAdmin gem for internal use and the decision was made to not cover ActiveAdmin functionality in our test coverage. Does anyone know how we can exempt the /app/admin folder from coveralls so that it doesn't drag our score down?

Answer (score 15):

How I was able to solve this:

1. Added file '.simplecov' to project root
2. In '.simplecov' added code:

   ```
   require 'simplecov'
   require 'coveralls'

   SimpleCov.formatter = Coveralls::SimpleCov::Formatter
   SimpleCov.start do
      add_filter 'app/admin'
   end
   ```

Basic instructions on this functionality is described at https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov#string-filter